# SELECT list expression references column location which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:8]

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

```
select location, max(new_vaccinations)
from `nomadic-vine-330117.PortfolioProject.Covid_Vaccinations` 
where  new_vaccinations = 
(
  select sum(new_vaccinations) as totalVaccinated
  from `nomadic-vine-330117.PortfolioProject.Covid_Vaccinations`
  where continent is not null
  group by location
  order by totalVaccinated desc
  limit 3
);
```

I am getting this error:

> SELECT list expression references column location which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:8]

It's bigquery.

Comment: You are selecting one row, because you aggregate the rows with max(new_vaccinations) and there is nio `GROUP BY` clause. But you are selecting a `location`. Which `location`? there are probably many in your table. You get this syntactically right, by either removing the `location` from your `SELECT` clause or by adding a `GROUP BY location`. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Inside the subquery you do group by location. This means the subquery results in one row per location. But then you compare the result via `where  new_vaccinations =`. You can't. You can use `=` when comparing two values. Use `IN` when looking for a value in a data set. But well, I don't know what you are actually trying to achieve. So I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: when I add group by location I get this: Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [1:19]

Comment: This is weird. Why would BigQuery forbid to read an aggregated intermediate result and aggregate again? This may be a side effect. As mentioned, your use of  `=` in combination with a subquery that returns more than one row is another error. Please explain what you want the query to do.

Comment: Okay. The query is completey messed up. Sorry to say so. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I know. thank you! will you post here?

Comment: Yes. How does the country come into play? Do locations belong to countries and you want the location per country that has the highest vaccination value? Is there one row per location in the table or many?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner country=location. edited the question

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am trying to get 3rd highest vaccination by location. I corrected to in but still getting error. inner query works and I can get 3 highest vaccinations. but not sure how to get the 3rd highest with outer query

Comment: I don't see your edit yet. So there are many rows for a location. You add them up, and then you compare the numbers. But what to do in case of ties? Say the top countrues/vaccinations are 3000, 3000, 2000, 2000, 1000, 1000, 900, 800. Which would you display? The two countries with the third highest number (1000)? Or is 3000 the highest value, 3000 the second highest, and 2000 the third highest and you woul pick one of the countries with 2000? Or what else?

Comment: with inner query I get 3 highest vaccinations. With the outer query I am trying to get the third highest from the inner query.  This is the inner query: select sum(new_vaccinations) as totalVaccinated
from `nomadic-vine-330117.PortfolioProject.Covid_Vaccinations` where continent is not null
group by location
order by totalVaccinated desc limit 3

Comment: And is it `sum(new_vaccinations)` you need or `max(new_vaccinations)` we must look at?

Comment: Yes, I understand 3rd highest when talking about the values 400, 300, 200, 100. It's 200 then. But if the values are 400, 400, 300, 200, 200, 100. Which is the third? 300? Or 200?

Comment: Well, 've posted an answer. You can adjust this accorsing to your specific needs.

Comment: in this case they are different but where to use disctinct? outer query?

Comment: No. `DISTINCT` is not the solution. And you haven't really answered my question either. I understand you want to rank all countries by their vaccination and then select the country on position #3. Is this correct? But then, what is position #3 in case of ties? Draw a table. Six countries/counts: US=400, GB=400, FR=300, DE=200, RU=200, PL=100. Which of the countries do you want to show? Or don't you want to show countries? Have I misunderstand this completely?

Answer (score 1):

There are syntax errors in your query:

- Aggregating to one final row and selecting one location without saying which.
- Comparing one value with a result set of possibly many rows with `=`.
- I think you cannot use the backticks on the whole path, but would have to use them on single names instead: `nomadic-vine-330117`.`PortfolioProject`.`Covid_Vaccinations`. I may be wrong here.

There are semantic errors in your query, too:

- The subquery returns one row per location. You pic three of them, but compare their total sum with a single row's value. This can only match if the three top locations just have one row in the table each. But then, why would you aggregate?

You say you want the 3rd highest vaccination by country (location). It seems, though, you really want the country on position 3 ranked by their vaccination instead. I may be wrong of course.

First step rank the countries by their vaccination count. Then pick #3.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    location,
    dense_rank() over(partition by country order by sum(new_vaccinations) desc) as rnk
  from `nomadic-vine-330117`.portfolioproject.covid_vaccinations cv
  group by location
) ranked
where rnk = 3;
```

Look at how this deals with ties and whether this is how you want to treat them.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt return anything. empty result

Comment: Then there are just up to two new_vaccinations sums. If all countries have a sum of 100 for instance, they are all on position #1, none is on position #3.

Comment: the table consists of all countries in all continents.

Comment: The below query fetches 3 top vaccinations numbers per country. I just need to fetch the 3rd highest one from it with outer query.                                          
           select  distinct sum(new_vaccinations) as totalVaccinated
from `nomadic-vine-330117.PortfolioProject.Covid_Vaccinations` where continent is not null
group by location
order by totalVaccinated desc limit 3

Comment: The table consists of all countries? It is a country table with one row per country/location? Why then the summing? I thought there are multiple entries per country that must be added up.

Comment: And you don't want to show any country in your results? With my example of countries/vaccinations US=400, GB=400, FR=300, DE=200, RU=200, PL=100, you simply want to select the number 200? Yes?

Comment: Yes it’s a table with all countries/locations. In inner query I grouped by country and got top 3 countries/locations highest vaccinations. In outer query I am trying to fetch the country/location with 3rd highest vaccination

Comment: Okay, one row per country means we don't have to use `SUM` at all. The `new_vaccinations` is already the country's total. vaccination. And as you do want to select a country, I am asking the third time: With countries/vaccinations US=400, GB=400, FR=300, DE=200, RU=200, PL=100, which country or countries would you want to select?